# IOS apps on Linux with RoboVM

Tags: java, ios, linux, robovm

I've managed to make an IOS app in objective C on Linux using this toolchain:
https://code.google.com/p/ios-toolchain-based-on-clang-for-linux/wiki/HowTo_en
I can write java in Linux obviously and get RoboVM plugin for Eclipse
Is there any way to build using the said toolchain, or any other?